# Obtaining list of folders from a webdav

Tags: iis, webdav

I am trying to get a list of folders in an array from a remote webdav. I am using the PROPFIND method querying for property 'isfolder', which although it is not standard it is contemplated in 'Additional WebDAV Collection Properties'. Then, I will parse the XML response to build up the array. However, in the response, I get a 'Resource not found' for this property. I am using the query against an IIS server.

My question, which seems to be answered already with my results (need confirmation though), is:
-Doesn't IIS have 'isfolder' property by default?

Then, how can I include it?

And, is there a better way to get a list of folders from a webdav directory?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I am getting a good result with 'iscollection'. It might actually be that I have got a wrong/bad expecification of webdav 'additional webdav Collection Properties'. If the resource is a folder, the 'iscollection' will be one; according to my results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any custom properties. Just check the DAV:resourcetype property.

Comment: Thank you for your post Julian. 'iscollection' is not a custom property; it is included in the 'Additional WebDav Collection Properties' specification. DAV:resourcetype returns 'collection' in the case of the resource being a directory and empty otherwise. 'iscollection' returns 1 or 0 respectively.

Comment: If 'iscollection' is standard, as I think, I rather use it as there are less bits in the response stream. My application checks very populated directories with a rather low satellite bandwidth.  Extract from a response:  <D:iscollection>1</D:iscollection> 
- <D:resourcetype>
  <D:collection /> 
  </D:resourcetype>

Comment: Well, it's not a "standard" and does not work with all servers. If you are concerned by bytes-on-the-wire. use Accept-Encoding: gzip.